# Foundry Breaks if You change your function's names, (WHY ?)?

Tags: solidity, foundry

Hope you are all doing great
I have this weird problem with naming my ***test*** functions in foundry, I am watching Patrick Collins New Videos collections.
in lesson 7(), patrick wrote a test name ***testFundFailsWithoutEnoughETH*** ([YouTube link to exact spot](https://youtu.be/sas02qSFZ74?t=4100)) to check if ***fund()*** function revert in case of not giving an enough value, and IT WORKS just like the videos.
I changed the name of the function to ***testFailWithoutEnoughETH()*** and now the function does NOT WORK.

Patrick's Code:

```
    function testFundFailWithoutEnoughETH() public {
        vm.expectRevert(); // this like tells solidity that we expect the next line to revert
        // fundMe.fund(); // send the function without enough eth, we must send at least MINIMUM_USD/ETH
    }
```

Terminal output for Patrik's code: (As expected, The test fails)

```bash
[⠑] Compiling...
[⠢] Compiling 1 files with 0.8.20
[⠆] Solc 0.8.20 finished in 1.30s
Compiler run successful!

Running 1 test for test/FundMeTest.t.sol:FundMeTest
[FAIL. Reason: Call did not revert as expected] testFundFailWithoutEnoughETH() (gas: 3045)
Test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 2.98ms
Ran 1 test suites: 0 tests passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped (1 total tests)

Failing tests:
Encountered 1 failing test in test/FundMeTest.t.sol:FundMeTest
[FAIL. Reason: Call did not revert as expected] testFundFailWithoutEnoughETH() (gas: 3045)

Encountered a total of 1 failing tests, 0 tests succeeded
```

---

My Code:

```
    function testFailWithoutEnoughETH() public {
        vm.expectRevert(); // this like tells solidity that we expect the next line to revert
        // fundMe.fund(); // send the function without enough eth, we must send at least MINIMUM_USD/ETH
    }
```

Terminal output for My Code: (MY Code Does Not Fail)

```bash
[⠑] Compiling...
[⠒] Compiling 1 files with 0.8.20
[⠢] Solc 0.8.20 finished in 1.26s
Compiler run successful!

Running 1 test for test/FundMeTest.t.sol:FundMeTest
[PASS] testFailWithoutEnoughETH() (gas: 3112)
Test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 1.24ms
Ran 1 test suites: 1 tests passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped (1 total tests)
```

---

Fund function:

```
function fund() public payable {
        require(msg.value.getConversionRate(s_priceFeed) >= MINIMUM_USD, "You need to spend more ETH!");
        // require(PriceConverter.getConversionRate(msg.value) >= MINIMUM_USD, "You need to spend more ETH!");
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
}
```

---

My big concern is that i am suppose to test my contracts, and now i dont know even if my test are reliable or not, because they may act different with different names.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the fact that the `testFail` is a reserved keyword for foundry.

Take it this way. So, whenever we start the function name with `test`, foundry knows that this is a test function and it needs to run the function.

Similarly, when we start the name with `testFail`, foundry knows that this function is a **test function that is supposed to revert**.

So basically testFail is a keyword to tell foundry that we are expecting this function to revert.

When you are writing `testFail`, you don't need to write `vm.expectRevert` again

Watch this small video, and it will be clear. https://youtu.be/yY9lL4Jxkd8